# Simple Q-learning neural network using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import exp, array, random, dot

R = np.matrix([[-1, -1, -1, -1,1, -1],        # for correct action the 
reward is 1 and for wrong action it's -1                     
           [-1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1],
           [-1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1],
           [-1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1],
           [-1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1],
           [-1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1]])

Q = np.matrix(np.zeros([6, 6]))  # Q matrix

gamma = 0.99  # Gamma (learning parameter).
lr = 0.1  # learning rate
initial_state = 1  # Initial state. 
w = 2*np.random.random((6,1)) - 1  # random weights for each action

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + exp(-x))

def sigmoid_derivative(x):
    return x * (1 - x)

def available_actions(state):  # This function returns all available actions 
in the state given as an argument
    current_state_row = R[state,]
    return current_state_row

def sample_next_action(available_actions_range):  # This function chooses at 
random which action to be performed within the rangeof all the available 
actions.
    next_action = int(np.random.choice(available_actions_range, 1))
    print("next_action: ", next_action)
    return next_action

def update(action, gamma,predict):  # This function updates the Q matrix 
according to the path selected 

    Q[current_state, action] = action + gamma * predict
    return Q[current_state, action]

for i in range(1000): ## Training
    current_state = np.random.randint(0, int(Q.shape[0]))
    available_act = np.array(available_actions(current_state))
    action = np.max(available_act)

    Qout = np.multiply(available_act,w) # forward propagation # multiplying 
    the selected action with the weights)
    predict = sigmoid(np.max(Qout))
    Qtarget = update(action, gamma, predict)  # target q values(rewards)
    loss = np.sum(Qtarget - Qout) # backward prop # calculating the error 
     between predicted and target q values
    adjustment = np.multiply(action ,loss , Qout)
    w = w + adjustment # adjusting weights
    Q += Qout

print("Trained network:")
print("--------")
print("weights : ", w)
np.set_printoptions(precision=2,suppress=True)
print(Q / np.max(Q) * 100)  # Normalize the "trained" Q matrix
```

I am a newbie into neural networks and reinforcement learning. I am trying to create a neural network (for learning purpose) which contains a single neuron with 6 inputs and 1 output. The problems that I am facing are as follows -

1. I am not sure if the way I am trying to predict the Q value through my Q network is correct ? and I am unsure as the calculation that I am doing to find out the target Q value is correct.
2. When I run the code the weights become 'Nan' after a few iterations and this leads the Q matrix to have all the Nan values.

Comment: I believe `sigmoid_derivative` is incorrect. It shouldn't be `x * (1 - x)` it should be `sigmoid(x) * (1 - sigmoid(x))`.

Comment: @Dair but if your `x` has already been `sigmoid`ed, then it's correct. I guess that's what OP is doing

Comment: HI @Dair thanks for the reply, but I ham not deriving the sigmoid_derivative in the above code. The function that you see is just a placeholder and as of now doesn't has any usage.